# PHP Declarar una variable de entorno

Tags: php, env

querría saber como puedo tener una variable de entorno en un proyecto PHP para, básicamente, tener una URL (para distinguir entre localhost y otra URL) y cambiarla en un solo sitio en vez de en absolutamente todos los ficheros .php que componen la aplicación. Lo he intentado con la superglobal $GLOBALS, pero cuando intento acceder a este desde una página que no es donde se creó, me sale vacío. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: un archivo de constantes no te serviría mejor?

Comment: podes usar [`phpdotenv`](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv) requiere composer. es bastante util para definir las variables en un archivo `.env` ( generalmente gitignored y comiteas un `.env.example` )

Comment: He probado phpdotenv pero no me funciona bien, y bueno, no pude arreglarlo. He optado por almacenarlo en la $_SESSION, aunque no sea una buena práctica me hace el apaño hasta que encuentre una solución factible